# Magento 2.0 Programmatically get the prefix used for Tables

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, prefix

I am doing some raw sql opertaions and would like to know if there is a way to get programmatically the Prefix used for the tables (the prefix you set during the Magento installation)?

Comment: The prefix is set in the app/etc/env.php file. Just parse that array out and grab the value for 'table_prefix'

Comment: what's the correct way of getting the values from env?

Comment: You can grab them via the Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig and the getConfigData method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get the prefix by using the function `getTableName()` like below :
Always use `getTableName` with raw queries to fetch the table along with the prefix dynamically

```
 protected $_resource;

 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
    ) {
    $this->_resource = $resource;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
    
public function execute()
{
    
    $connection  = $this->_resource->getConnection();
    $tableName   = $this->_resource->getTableName('tablename_without_prefix'); // It will return table with prefix

    $mapsDeleteQuery = "your raw SQL Query";
    $connection->query($mapsDeleteQuery);
}
```

You can also get the prefix from the file `app/etc/env.php`

```
'db' => 
  array (
    'table_prefix' => '', // if any prefix is used, you can see here
    'connection' => 
    array (
      'default' => 
      array (
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'dbname' => 'magento2',
        'username' => 'abc',
        'password' => 'abc',
        'active' => '1',
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: i tested this but it's not return the table name with the prefix.  its just return the table name.  on your example, its still returning customer_entity instead of the expected prefix_customer_entity.

Comment: check my edited answer

Comment: hi manashvi, how do you get that array in the env.php?  does magento have a method to get it?

Comment: No there is no such way to fetch the array in env.php. The code specified above that should work.

Comment: oh ok i now get the table name with prefix.  the correct code is **$this->_resource->getTableName("tablename without prefix");**

Comment: yes exactly.!!!

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old topic, but the right answer is not the accepted one, so I felt I should share the right code for someone who's looking for this.

The code below works:

```
 protected $_resource;

 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
    ) {
    $this->_resource = $resource;
    parent::__construct($context);
 }

 public function execute()
 {
    $this->_resource->getTableName("tablename without prefix");
 }
```

The code below does not work, and will not do anything. Note that there is a crucial difference:

```
$connection  = $this->_resource->getConnection();
$tableName   = $connection->getTableName('tablename_without_prefix');
```

Comment: Works, thank you!

Comment: works for me, thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
    $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);    
    $obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
    $deploymentConfig = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig');
    var_dump($deploymentConfig->get('db/table_prefix'));
```

References:

[Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/DeploymentConfig.php)

[Magento's Deployment Configuration](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/config/config-php.html)