# Magento 2: get table name on collection join

Tags: magento2, database, collection, resources

I have a Magento 2 collection and I want to JOIN more tables to this collection's select:

```
public function prepareProductCollection(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection) {
    $query = $collection->getSelect();
    $alias = 'mot';
    $name = 'my_own_table';
    $on = "...";
    $cols = ['col1', 'col2'];
    $query->joinLeft([$alias => $name], $on, $cols);        
}
```

How can I get table name with prefix if I have `$collection` variable only? This case returns table name itself (w/o prefix):

```
$query->getConnection()->getTableName('my_own_table')
```

Comment: You can check with http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110907/magento-2-0-programmatically-get-the-prefix-used-for-tables and http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131007/i-need-table-name-with-prefix-in-custom-controller-file-magento-2

Comment: use Just use  `$collection->getTable('my_own_table');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

`$collection->getResource()->getTable('YOUR_TABLE');`

Even this class is also getting table name with this way. Just look at `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection` this

`$this->getResource()->getTable('catalog_product_website');`